# Regex exclude whitespaces from a group to select only a number

Tags: regex, text, numbers

I need to take only a number (a float number) from a text, but I can't remove the whitespaces...

[image]

** Update

[image]

I have a problem with this method, I only need to consider numbers and ',' between '- EUR' and 'Fee' as rule.

Comment: You should use capturing, `- EUR\s*(.*?)\s*Fee`, and get Group 1 in your code. You might use `\K` in some regex engines, `- EUR\s*\K.*?(?=\s*Fee)`, or even a lookbehind, ``(?<=- EUR\s*).*?(?=\s*Fee)``

Comment: I tried with this method but I have a problem, see the Update please.

Comment: Ok, use `- EUR\W*(.*?)\W*Fee`

Comment: So did it work for you in the end? You surely can use a more sophisticated `- EUR\W*(\d[.,\d]*)\W*Fee\b` pattern, but I assumed you always have digits/number between `EUR` and `Fee`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
- EUR\W*(.*?)\W*Fee
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3aP4h/1).

*Variations of the regex that might work in different regex engines*:

```js
- EUR\W*\K.*?(?=\W*Fee)
(?<=- EUR\W*).*?(?=\W*Fee)
```

*Details*:

- `- EUR` -  literal text
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\W*`-  zero or more non-word chars
- `Fee` - a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could also match the number format in capture group 1

```
- EUR\b\D*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s+Fee\b
```

- `- EUR\b` Match `- EUR` and a word boundary
- `\D*` Match 0+ times any char except a digit
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+Fee\b` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `Fee` and a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pnUIue/1)

Answer (score 0):

this is working i removed the , from (.) in test string.

[Regex example -  working](https://regex101.com/r/7CxNu8/1)

Comment: I need to consider a float with the comma ',' between '- EUR' and 'Fee'